# Are there any rule functions in Firebase Database Rules that can allow read access to a specific value only during certain events?

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So this is an example structure of my data:

```
"userPublic" : {
"uid" : {
  "fullName" : "name",
  "userImg" : "picture url"
  "email" : "fake email"
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to allow a user to invite another user to a group. This process involves searching for the user by email, which is stored under their uid. I need the uid when adding a user to a group, so I want to use the email to find the correct user's uid.

Now, usually what I would do is run a query and only grab the uid with the value of the requested email. Currently I have the rules set up so that any authenticated user can read the info in "userPublic"

However, because of privacy, I do not want the user requesting this information to always have read access to the email value specifically. **Instead I want the user to have read access to the email value only if the email they use to search matches it. I'm trying to figure out how to allow read access to the value within email only if the user requesting it uses that specific email-address, but also still allow read access to everything else within uid.**

Since rules in Firebase cascade, I know that one option is to separate the always readable values in one key and the email in another; however, that still leaves me stumped on how I would make the email only readable during certain events. I also thought of making a temporary node in which the searched email address is stored. and then setting a rule like

```
".read" : "email.val() === 
           root.child(tempNode).child(auth.uid).child(email).val()"
```

but this whole process seems too complicated and long, especially for client-side code.

So are there any rule functions in Firebase Database that can allow read access to a specific value/node only during certain events? If not, are there any simpler workarounds to this than what was previously mentioned?

Comment: Security rules don't know anything about Cloud Functions.